# Show Label in Material Slider when user stop to drag [KOTLIN]

Tags: android, kotlin, slider, material-design

it's possible to make this?

I'm using `com.google.android.material.slider.Slider` and I know that `setLabelFormatter` event allows you to see or modify the label when you're dragging the Material Slider but I want to get the value when user stop to drag to know the current value that Material Slider has

[image]

Something like this (without getting pressed to take ss haha lol)

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more recent version, `LABEL_VISIBLE` is added as one of the **LabelBehavior** value:

> LABEL_FLOATING: The label will only be visible on interaction. It will float above the slider and may cover views above this one. This is the default and recommended behavior.
>
> LABEL_WITHIN_BOUNDS: The label will only be visible on interaction. The label will always be drawn within the bounds of this view. This means extra space will be visible above the slider when the label is not visible.
>
> LABEL_GONE: The label will never be drawn.
>
> **LABEL_VISIBLE: The label will never be hidden.**

So you can set the above value if you would like to always show the current value of the slider.

Example in XML:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
    ...
    app:labelBehavior="visible" />
```

Or in code:

```kotlin
slider.labelBehavior = LabelFormatter.LABEL_VISIBLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the material components Slider source code to see how/when it decides to display its label.

- there doesn't seem to be any public APIs to allow us to make it show up....
- it shows up when it receives the touch down event....

I wrote some functions to trick the material slider into thinking that it's being touched, triggering the label to show.

```kotlin
fun Slider.showLabelForever()
{
    // start showing the label immediately
    showLabelUntilNextTouchUp()

    // send a touch event when user stops touching the slider to trigger the
    // label to show up again
    addOnSliderTouchListener(
        object:Slider.OnSliderTouchListener
        {
            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(slider:Slider) = Unit
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(slider:Slider) = showLabelUntilNextTouchUp()
        }
    )
}

fun Slider.showLabelUntilNextTouchUp()
{
    // sent a touch event to cause the label for the slider to show.
    // a side effect of calling onTouchEvent is that it will cause
    // the slider to change the progress value; we save the original
    // progress value before calling onTouchEvent, then restore the
    // value after calling onTouchEvent.
    val originalValue = value
    onTouchEvent(
        MotionEvent.obtain(0L,0L,MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,0f,0f,0)
    )
    value = originalValue
}
```

Comment: doesn"t work for me :(  It shows the halo around the thumb only fron start, after stop dragging dissapers, and didn't show label

Comment: @OlenaY hmmmmmmm please make sure that after calling `showLabelForever()` on the label, that this is not happening: `app:labelBehavior="gone"`, and also that `clearOnSliderTouchListeners()` is never called on the Slider....does that work?

Comment: I have  app:labelBehavior="withinBounds", and don't clean the listeners... =(